# Log4j is required or not in Websphere Environment when using Commons Logging

Tags: log4j, websphere, websphere-8, apache-commons-logging

I would like to get the recommendation for implementing the logging in our application. Here is the current scenario:

1. In the existing application we are using the Apache Commons Logging for printing the log messages.
2. We have not sent the log4j.xml (it is due to fault in the build file) with our application, this makes all the logs to be printed in the SystemOut.log file in the websphere server.
3. Since, we are not doing the continuous support to that application, we don't require continuous monitoring of the application messages. In this case, is it good practice to use log4j.xml and redirect the log messages to separate log files or let the websphere log the messages to it's default log files.

Please suggest some best practice to handle this situation. Currently, the log levels are set in the Web Sphere configurations.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have requirement for separate logs and log4j, I wouldn't use it in WebSphere. By using standard JUL you can easily change the log level during runtime using WebSphere admin console, without any chanages/restarts/redeployments of the application.

If you need application logs, you can also consider switching WAS to HPEL logging, which allows monitoring for specific log entries and filtering. See more [High Performance Extensible Logging (HPEL)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1208_bourne/1208_bourne.html)